# XSL how to check for commas in a url?

Tags: xml, string, url, xslt, contains

```
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="./link/@href ">
  <td class="link"> <a href="{@href}"> 
    <xsl:copy-of select="./link/@href"/>Link</a> </td>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
  <td class="nolink"> <a href="{@href}"> 
   <xsl:copy-of select="./link/@href"/>Link</a> </td>
 </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Given the following code, I want to add another test to see whether my href-url link has got one or more commas in it. If that's true I want to assign a different class to the td. Maybe checking for no comma would be even better. 
I thought about "contains" but I don't know how to set up the structure for that.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Why would a URL have a comma in it? Why would having a comma mean it needed a different class? Why are you trying to do this in XSLT instead of in the browser where you could probably use a CSS rule such as `td a[href*=","] { ... }`? The above code is also factored very poorly (actually not at all).

Comment: it's a special url for a program. So having one comma in there would mean two links are pointing to two different "documents". If there's no comma - it's just one link. I simply want to display a different icon if there are two or more links within the url. I'd be happy to be shown a better method compared to what I have here.

Comment: Wherever the XML is coming from upstream, it is poor design to put multiple links into a single @href attribute, forcing you to identify them and parse them yourself in the XSL. I'd suggest having the XML generated so that each link comes in its own `link` element. Then you could check using something like `count(link)>1` if you wanted to be able to find entries with more than one link in order to visually distinguish them or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the xpath function **contains** would be the way to go, but one way to approach this is that instead of having an **xsl:choose** make use of templates to match the cases you want. So, you would start by looking for any **link** element

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="link"/>
```

And then you would have a template to match the **link** elements where the @href attributes contained a comman

```
<xsl:template match="link[contains(@href, ',')]">
```

You would also need a more general template to match all other **link** elements. This would only be matched if other more specific templates have not found a match

```
<xsl:template match="link">
```

For example, consider the following XML

```
<root>
   <doc>
      <link href="http://www.example.com" />
   </doc>
   <doc>
      <link href="http://www.example1.com,http://www.example2.com" />
   </doc>
</root>
```

When you apply the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="root">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="doc"/>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="doc">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="link"/>
      <xsl:if test="not(link[@href])">
         <td>No link</td>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="link[contains(@href, ',')]">
      <td class="link2">
         <xsl:call-template name="link">
            <xsl:with-param name="href" select="substring-before(@href, ',')"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
         <xsl:call-template name="link">
            <xsl:with-param name="href" select="substring-after(@href, ',')"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="link">
      <td class="link">
         <xsl:call-template name="link"/>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="link">
      <xsl:param name="href" select="@href"/>
      <a href="{$href}">
         <xsl:copy-of select="$href"/> Link</a>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then the following is output

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class="link">
         <a href="http://www.example.com"> Link</a>
      </td>
      <td class="link2">
         <a href="http://www.example1.com">http://www.example1.com Link</a>
         <a href="http://www.example2.com">http://www.example2.com Link</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Note this also makes use of a named template to avoid duplicating code.

EDIT: If you had multiple elements, as well as **link** which had @href attributes, there is a number of ways you could do it. If you had a limited number of names, you could do something like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="link|website|localpath" />
```

And then you could match them like this....

```
<xsl:template match="link[contains(@href, ',')]|website[contains(@href, ',')]|localpath[contains(@href, ',')]">

<xsl:template match="link|website|website" />
```

Better would be to look any element, like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
```

And then match any elements with an href attribute, and those without

```
<xsl:template match="doc/*[contains(@href, ',')]">

<xsl:template match="doc/*">
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed info. One question though. How would I need to edit this, if there were different names that contain href-attributes instead of of just <link>? 
Example: <website href="xyz"/> | <localpath href="xyz" />

Comment: I've expanded my answer to hopefully answer this!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this

```
<xsl:if test=".[contains(@href,',')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="class">myclass</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```